# Unity: trying to set a global shader property using .SetGlobalFloat

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, shader-graph

Im creating a 3d game in Unity, basically, I have a shader that the in game scanner uses, multiple things are scannable meaning there are multiple materials with the same shader. This shader is created using shader graph.

I want to globally modify a property in the shader across all materials that use it.

This is the line I am trying to use to modify the property:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButton(1))
    {
        scannableMat.shader.SetGlobalFloat("_offset", 2);
    }
}
```

However I get this error:

```
Member 'Shader.SetGlobalFloat(string, float)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead (CS0176)
```

I have tried disabling the exposed setting but that didn't work. Im pretty new to shadergraph so I dont know if what I want it to do is possible, however any work around that achieve the same thing would be appreciated. Sorry if this is an easy fix, thanks in advance.

Comment: `SetGlobalFloat` is a static method, so you should use `Shader.SetGlobalFloat("_offset", 2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note that it doesn't make sense to set a "Global Float" for a single material.

Probably what you are looking for is really only `scannableMat.SetFloat("_offset", 2)`. However, if your material is an *instance* of the original material, this wouldn't work and setting a global shader value would be a better option.

If you have a reference for a MeshRenderer and your materials are not instances, you can use `meshRenderer.sharedMaterial.SetFloat("_offset", 2)`.

Lastly, if you really want to set a global value for all shaders, try `Shader.SetGlobalFloat("_offset", 2)`.

Comment: thanks, just to clarify this was the solution i was looking, Shader.SetGlobalFloat("_offset", 2). not sure why it got tagged as duplicate considering the circumstances of this and the associated issue are so different but i hope other people having the same issue find this.